# Run two independents communicative thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run a thread who display data calculated by another (thread) without waiting it.
Peace of code try to explain it (python3):

```
from time import sleep, time


class Display:

    def __init__(self):
        self._current_frame = 0
        self._data = 0

    def run(self):
        start_time = time()
        while True:  # Expect: infinite loop still Core is running
            sleep(0.5)
            self._current_frame = i
            print(round(time()-start_time, 2), 'Display frame is', self._current_frame, 'and data is', self._data)

    def receive(self, data):
        self._data = data


class Core:

    def __init__(self):
        self._display = Display()

    def start(self):
        # Expected: Run Display in thread and continue
        self._display.run()
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(2)
            # When Core finish to compute a frame, It send data to the thread
            self._display.receive(i)

core =  Core()
core.start()
```

What i want is: Display print his messages independently of the Core computing. Regulary, Core send to Display new datas. Display have not to wait Core.

Like Pipes with Processs.

The output should be:

```
0.5 Display frame is 0 and data is 0
1.0 Display frame is 1 and data is 0
1.5 Display frame is 2 and data is 0
2.0 Display frame is 3 and data is 1
2.5 Display frame is 4 and data is 0
3.0 Display frame is 5 and data is 0
3.51 Display frame is 6 and data is 0
4.01 Display frame is 7 and data is 2
4.51 Display frame is 8 and data is 0
5.01 Display frame is 9 and data is 0
[...]
```

Can i do that with threads ? If yes how ?

Comment: Are you looking for a [synchronized queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)?

Comment: If i don't mistake, with a Queue, process can't communicate between them. And main process (who launch eueue) wait the end of queue to continue his process.

Comment: I don't understand your concern. Queue exists specifically to facilitate communication between threads. Your thread can wait until there is something in queue, but it can also check if there is something with `get_nowait`. I find it difficult to understand what you are actually trying to do, so I can't really suggest you what is the right way.

Comment: @zch So i mistake with threads. Can you provide an answer with it ?

Comment: I can't really tell you if threads are a mistake, because I don't really know what the problem is and why you think that you need them. I wouldn't use threads for printing 000100020003..., but I expect your actual problem is more complex.

Comment: Yes my problem is more complex. But if you show me how print 000100020003 with threads i will be able to resolve my more complex problem !

Comment: Good smell: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes